# How to create animated splash screen not with Images in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, core-animation

I want to know that how one should proceed in building animated splash screen.
I already did the animated splash screen with images but here I want to add custom animation like something is drawn on screen etc.
can anyone guide me through this.

Comment: i am not demanding any source code, i just need guidance that whether we can do a small animation clip or go with the core animation??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply you need to present a `UIViewController` which is hold your animations and dismiss it when your app is ready to launch. but also I think its better to follow apple [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5) .. as apple describe you should

> Supply a launch image to improve user experience.
>
> Avoid using your launch image as an opportunity to provide:
>
> An “application entry experience,” such as a splash screen An About
>   window Branding elements, unless they are a static part of your
>   application’s first screen Because users are likely to switch among
>   applications frequently, you should make every effort to cut launch
>   time to a minimum, and you should design a launch image that downplays
>   the experience rather than drawing attention to it.
>
> Generally, design a launch image that is identical to the first screen
>   of the application.
>
> Exceptions:
>
> Text. The launch image is static, so any text you display in it will
>   not be localized.
>
> UI elements that might change. Avoid including elements that might
>   look different when the application finishes launching, so that users
>   don’t experience a flash between the launch image and the first
>   application screen.